# Possible error in the oracle java tutorial?

Tags: java, file, io, nio

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) Oracle Java tutorial:

> The asFileAttribute method accepts a Set of file permissions and
>   constructs a file attribute that can be passed to the Path.createFile
>   or Path.createDirectory method.

Did they mean `Files.createFile`?

Comment: It certainly looks like it, yes. You should probably report a bug, however I don't know where it could be filled.

Comment: Given that it's Oracle, probably in the memory hole.

Comment: @chrylis Actually they tend to fix errors in the Java tutorial quite efficiently... More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/feedback.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation was correct but is no more up to date.

In the [JDK7 build b129](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b129/), the abstract method [Path.createFile](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b129/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) was present in the abstract class [Path](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b129/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html). In the [JDK 7 build b130](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b130) the abstract Path class becomes an [interface](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b130/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and the method was moved in the [Files class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29).

Here is a link to the [changeset](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/rev/236e3f2d0a6b) in the [OpenJDK 7 mercurial repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/).

```
-public abstract class Path 
-    implements FileRef, Comparable<Path>, Iterable<Path>, Watchable
+public interface Path
+    extends Comparable<Path>, Iterable<Path>, Watchable
```

and a link to the related [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7006126) in the JDK bug system.